# Push SQL data to Microsoft Project Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, project-management, ms-project

I have mobile apps that store real-time information on my SQL Server database (hosted by Azure). I also have Microsoft Project Professional (Stored locally).

I am looking to integrate my SQL data and the Projects.

Is there a way to push data (maybe using queries/scripts) to Project Server? (I have not installed Project server yet as i need to be sure if there is a way to connect the two before i take that step.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. You can however use VBA to read SQL data in project client so Project can save it in Project Server or you can write CSOM code to the Project Server APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You might very well integrate through VBA between MS Projects Stored Locally and the database. You may not need Project Server just for the integration purpose.